# Use Skip and Limit for parent nodes, having many sub-nodes cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, nodes, limit, skip

I am new to neo4j cypher stuff, I am just trying to achieve pagination with `SKIP` and `LIMIT`.

I have `Employee` node and Task node, Employee can have multiple tasks and one task can be assigned to multiple employees.
Employee and Task have `assignment` relationship which is created based on task assigned to employee or his department.

Actually there are 100+ tasks which are assigned to eid = 'RD23233' or department= 'R&D'

To get first 50 tasks of employee/employees, I am using below query,

```
MATCH (e:Employee)-[ass]->(c:Task) 
where e.department= 'R&D' or e.eid='RD23233'
WITH distinct c as t,ass,e 
ORDER BY t.taskId  
SKIP 0 LIMIT 50
RETURN t,ass,e
```

Here I am getting first 10 tasks only, because it is actually limiting the employee node.
Where as I am expecting task nodes.

How to limit task node with this above query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After multiple try, I could able to create below query which limits the task nodes.

```
MATCH (e:Employee)-[ass]->(t:Task) 
where e.department= 'R&D' or e.eid='RD23233' 
WITH distinct t as c  
ORDER BY t.karmTaskId DESC 
SKIP 0 LIMIT 50 
MATCH (e:Employee)-[ass]->(c)
RETURN c,ass,e
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
MATCH (e:Employee)-[ass]->(c:Task) 
where e.department= 'R&D' or e.eid='RD23233'
WITH c AS task, COLLECT(e) AS employees 
ORDER BY task.taskId  
SKIP 0 LIMIT 50
UNWIND employees AS emp
MATCH (task)<-[ass]-(emp)
RETURN task,ass,emp
```

Comment: here 50 limit is on all the tasks, and first 50  can not have those  employees tasks.
and It would return nothing

Comment: Yes its limits task nodes, Thanks.
I found another which is also working,.

Comment: Can you share the other one as well?